# Sending data to ASP.NET through jQuery Ajax() gives error

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to send data to an ASP.NET programme with jQuery with this code:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "http://localhost:52930/api/person/",
    data: JSON.stringify({Name: "Sinan", Password: 'test'})
})
    .done(function( msg ) {
        alert(msg)
    });
```

The header information shows that the data was sent. But when I put a breakpoint in the asp.net script it shows that the values arn't received and it gives me this error:

[image]

This is the header information from the jQuery request:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

And change `method` to `type`.

Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "http://localhost:52930/api/person/",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({
      Name: "Sinan",
      Password: 'test'
    })
  })
  .done(function(msg) {
    alert(msg)
  });
```

Comment: Wow thanks this fixed it! I didn't think it would be something this simple.